# Tooltip for bar Chart using d3-tip in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I created Bar chart using d3.js in angular, but now i want tool-tip for it.
I installed d3-tip with command 'npm install d3-tip' and imported this package as "import * as d3Tip from 'd3-tip'". But it is showing me following error, 'd3_tip__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.tip is not a function'.

My code for tool-tip as follow

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3Tip from 'd3-tip';

var tip = d3Tip.tip.attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return d; });

var tip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return d; })
svg.call(tip);

g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("fill", "red");
     })
     .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", function() {
            return "" + d.partNumber + "";
        });
     })
     .enter().append("rect")
       .attr("class", "bar")
       .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.partNumber); })
       .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
       .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
       .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value)
    });
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you post some code?